# Html email variables?

Tags: html, email, variables

I have task to make elements in html email with variables like this:

```
v1: %email.content.title%
v2: %email.content.description% 
v3: %email.content.btn.text%
```

I don't understand why I need to use variables?

How to use variables when email services block all dynamic data?

Can you write me a simple example or send me a link when I can read about those types of variables?

Comment: you can place those variables in some json file with translations, usually that dynamic content. should be injected in html template before generating email, so you have to do email generation on your server side and send them over email service.

Comment: "How to use variables when email services block all dynamic data?" — Write software that outputs HTML and sends it in an email.